# Como detectar a causa do erro: 'The requested URL returned error: 503'?

Tags: linux, apache, http

Estou a trabalhar no desenvolvimento de um web-site onde de volta e meia recebo o seguinte erro que consigo ver através do [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/):

> The requested URL returned error: 503

Existe alguma forma de descobrir a origem deste problema, talvez através de logs ou algo do género para que o possa resolver?

<sup>**Nota:**

Se esperar uns segundos e fizer a actualização da página, "recebo" o web-site em condições, ou seja, sem o erro.</sup>

Comment: Veja isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299086/how-to-detect-cause-of-503-service-temporarily-unavailable-error-and-handle-it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O código de erro 503 do HTTP significa que o serviço solicitado ao servidor WEB não está disponível, o Apache geralmente apresenta tal erro quando não consegue atender a requisição em questão, vários podem ser os motivos, entre eles:

- Excesso de requisições ao servidor, que se torna instável.
- Erro interno gerado por alguma configuração errônea.
- Falta de recursos disponíveis no servidor para atender a requisição.
- Dentre outros.

Para encontrar tais erros, o apache fornece dois locais onde procurar pelos erros, o **ErrorLog** e **AccessLog**, em uma configuração padrão do apache, esses logs podem ser encontrados em

- **/var/log/apache2/error.log**
- **/var/log/apache2/access.log**

respectivamente.

Caso esteja trabalhando com mais de um host virtual em sua instalação, eles podem ou não estarem sendo gravados em locais distintos.

Para gravar os logs do host virtual site.com por exemplo, adicione as seguintes linhas a sessão `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>` correspondente:

```
CustomLog /meu/caminho/onde/quero/salvar/os/logs/site.com.log combined
ErrorLog /meu/caminho/onde/quero/salvar/os/logs/site.com.error.log
```

e então os arquivos `site.com.log` e `site.com.error.log` irão contem os logs de acesso e erro, respectivamente.